# Procedure and open cursor

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE create_rule(
      p_rule_type_key   IN VARCHAR2,
      p_key             IN VARCHAR2,
      p_activation      IN DATE,
      p_termination     IN DATE,
      p_description     IN VARCHAR2
    )
IS
   CURSOR cur_rules (pc_rule_type_key IN VARCHAR2, pc_key IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
      SELECT rule_type_key
      FROM ino_offers.rules
      WHERE rule_type_key = pc_rule_type_key
      AND key             = pc_key;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_rules (p_rule_type_key, p_key);
   p_description2     IN VARCHAR2;
   FETCH cur_rules INTO p_description2;
   IF (cur_rules%NOTFOUND) THEN
      INSERT
      INTO rules
         (
            RULE_TYPE_KEY,
            KEY,
            ACTIVATION,
            TERMINATION,
            DESCRIPTION,
            CHANGED
         )
         VALUES
         (
            p_rule_type_key,
            p_key,
            p_activation,
            p_termination,
            p_description,
            SYSDATE
         );
   END IF;
   CLOSE cur_rules;
END;
BEGIN
   create_rule(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
END;
```

but I get:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":= was inserted before "IN" to continue.
```

Problem is here:

```
OPEN cur_rules (p_rule_type_key, p_key);
       p_description2     IN VARCHAR2;
```

what is correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have declare p_description2     IN VARCHAR2 after the begin.That y you got the below  error.and you fetch cursor record into p_description2 variable so it should be cur_rules type.So try using like this p_description2 cur_rules%ROWTYPE;

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE create_rule(
      p_rule_type_key   IN VARCHAR2,
      p_key             IN VARCHAR2,
      p_activation      IN DATE,
      p_termination     IN DATE,
      p_description     IN VARCHAR2
    )
IS
   CURSOR cur_rules (pc_rule_type_key IN VARCHAR2, pc_key IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
      SELECT rule_type_key
      FROM ino_offers.rules
      WHERE rule_type_key = pc_rule_type_key
      AND key             = pc_key;
 p_description2 cur_rules%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_rules (p_rule_type_key, p_key);
   FETCH cur_rules INTO p_description2;
   IF (cur_rules%NOTFOUND) THEN
      INSERT
      INTO rules
         (
            RULE_TYPE_KEY,
            KEY,
            ACTIVATION,
            TERMINATION,
            DESCRIPTION,
            CHANGED
         )
         VALUES
         (
            p_rule_type_key,
            p_key,
            p_activation,
            p_termination,
            p_description,
            SYSDATE
         );
   END IF;
   CLOSE cur_rules;
END;
BEGIN
   create_rule(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 p_description2     IN VARCHAR2;
```

What exactly do you want to do with that line?
If you'd like to declare a variable `p_description2`, you need to do inside the `DECLARE` part, just before the `BEGIN`.
While declaring it, do not use a `VARCHAR2`, but use a `CUR_RULES%ROWTYPE`, this is why pl/sql is powerful.